# How to create node-red flow to make a connection with fiware-orion-context-broker

Tags: node-red, fiware

I am trying to create a node-red flow to connect with my orion-context-broker instance but i am getting below error message:

failed to query, reason: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}

I choose fiware-orion-query from node-red menu then i configured my orion ip and port to it but its showing me error.

Comment: There isn't really enough information here, what node are you using? Also that error implies that it is is the remote end of the connection that is not allowing you to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I have always use a change node with http request like this:

```
Change node:
set msg.url url
set msg.method GET/POST
set msg.headers "JSON with all headers"
set msg.payload
```

then you add change box to http request with method selected via msg method option and it should work if you have everything configured.
It would be great to be able to check your code.
Kind Regards!